# Set a directory path for my entire site

Tags: php

On the website I'm administrating, I use several `include` and `require`. I would like to define the entire structure of the website in some config-file that is included on each page so I don't have to worry about paths any more and no matter where the file is located, `include('any_filename.php');` will always work.
I'd like to add that the site is on a shared host and I don't have full control of absolute paths or any .ini-file. The directory structure looks like this:

```
myDomainName.com
|
+-public_html
  |
  +-pictures
  |
  +-include
  |
  +-templates
```

where myDomainName.com is as high as I can go.
Or is there a smarter way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to have a constant containing your base directory:

```
define("BASE_DIR", "/myDomainName.com/public_html/");
```

And have all subsequent files to include in the form of:

```
include BASE_DIR . "any_file.php";
```

If your PHP version is above 4.3.0 (very likely), you could also use [**`set_include_path()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Comment: Then you run into chicken/egg... need a path to include that file, but don't want to use any paths...

Comment: Yes, but then I only have to worry about ONE path, the path to the config-file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) that is built-in to PHP.